# How to separate date and time from single string variable?

Tags: string, jsp, date, servlets, time

I have stored date and time in single string variable on my jsp page. Now i want to separate date and time to sore them in new variables date and time. I don't know how to separate them from string. Can anyone tell?

Comment: Use JSTL tags which work as server side code. that may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JSTL: `<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>`

1. parse string as date using `<fmt:parseDate>`
2. format this date as two strings using `<fmt:formatDate>` (for storing into new variable, use the `var` tag attribute; for separating the date and time, use the `type` attribute)

Comment: You are welcome! Kindly consider closing this question by accepting my answer if it helped you solve your problem, thanks.